# Replace string enclosed in specified characters based on data type

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I need to replace characters enclosed in `<...>` in my PHP string. I did this with `preg_replace()`, but I need to modify this code to do more.

Here is my code :

```
$templateText = "Hi <John> , This is a test message from <9876543210>";
$repl = "test";
$patt = "/\<([^\]]+)\>/"; 
echo $template_sample  = preg_replace($patt, $repl , $templateText);
```

The above code will replace the first occurrence of value enclosed in `<...>` with `test`.

E.g. the above code will display string like:

```
Hi test
```

However, I need to replace it with `test` only if it is not numeric. if the enclosed value is numeric then it should be replaced with `999999999`.

What I'm expecting is:

```
Hi test , This is a test message from 999999999
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `preg_replace_callback` with a regex that will match either digits or any 0+ chars other than `>` between `<...>` and use a custom logic for replacement:

```
$templateText = "Hi <John> , This is a test message from <9876543210>";
$template_sample = preg_replace_callback("/<(?:(\d+)|[^>]*)>/", function($m) {
    return !empty($m[1]) ? '999999999' : 'test';
}, $templateText);
echo $template_sample; // => Hi test , This is a test message from 999999999
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/yha3Aq).

**Pattern details**

- `<` - a literal `<` (this is not a special regex metacharacter, do not escape)
- `(?:(\d+)|[^>]*)` - a non-capturing group matching either of:

  - `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
  - `|` - or
  - `[^>]*` - any 0+ chars other than `>`
- `>` - a literal `>` (this is not a special regex metacharacter, do not escape).

The replacement is a callback function that gets `$m` match object and checks if Group 1 was matched. If Group 1 value is not empty (`!empty($m[1])`) the match is replaced with `999999999`, else with `test`.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, for your quick response. Its perfectly fine. and thanks for your detail explanation